# Which country has the highest share of GDP that's attributed to housing?

Tags: economy, international, gdp

https://www.axios.com/2023/10/11/chart-chinas-real-estate-struggles

> Why it matters: At its peak, China's residential property sector was
> thought to contribute an estimated 25%-30% of the country's GDP. Its
> ongoing struggles present a challenge to economic growth in China that
> will ripple out to other nations — as China has been the largest
> single source of growth for the world economy in recent decades.

Which country has the highest share of GDP that's attributed to housing? By housing I mean (1) imputed rent; (2) actual rent; and (3) residential investment (construction of new housing). I am thinking Canada might have the largest share, but I am not sure. Is there a graph with every country, because I was also wondering if China had more of its GDP tied to housing than the U.S.

Comment: *highest share of GDP ... By housing, I mean rent and property value tied to home, which contributes to an individual's net worth.* Property value does not enter GDP. What does enter GDP are (1) imputed rent; (2) actual rent; and (3) residential investment (construction of new housing).

Comment: Note that the high percentage in China comes from the fact that so much new housing was build in the last few decades. The proportion of the Chinese population living in buildings that were newly constructed in the last 20 or 30 years is much higher than in most other countries in the world. Among major countries China might actually be the answer to yoru question.

Comment: Interestingly enough, and contrary to what I thought, it's not just construction that goes into housing-to-GDP calculations, but also *rents* and rent-equivalents: [USA](https://www.nahb.org/news-and-economics/housing-economics/housings-economic-impact/housings-contribution-to-gross-domestic-product) : Residential investment (averaging roughly 3-5% of GDP), which includes **construction** ... /  *Consumption spending on housing services (averaging roughly 12-13% of GDP), which includes **gross rents and utilities paid by renters, as well as owners’ imputed rents** and utility payments.*

Comment: In the US is said to be 15%-18% https://www.nahb.org/news-and-economics/housing-economics/housings-economic-impact/housings-contribution-to-gross-domestic-product So, I guess not the US.

Comment: While there is often overlap between economic questions and political ones, I'm struggling to see how this is a Politics.SE question.